# How to only log in users who have are verified in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The users have a field in the database called verified which is a boolean. It is set to 0 by default, and is then set to '1' when the user follows a verification link sent to them via email upon registration.

I need users who have this boolean value set to 0 to be rejected when attempting to log in, and a message to flash to the screen explaining why they have been rejected. Users who have verification set to '1' will be logged in as usual.

I have written this 'authenticated' method in AuthController.php, this method is utilized by 'handleUserWasAuthenticated' method in AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
    public function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
      if($user->verified==false)
      {
          flash('you are not verified');
          return redirect('/login');
      }

      return redirect('/');
    }
```

Here is the 'handleUserWasAuthenticated' method which utilizes it.

```
 protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This is currently not working. The verified users are being logged in and sent to the home page. However, the unverified users are also being logged in, but returned to a different page.

I forgot to mention, I did not write the second method above, it was generated like the other methods in 'AuthenticatesUser.php' when I used the make:auth command.

Comment: Try using After Validation Hook  -  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation. If user is registered but not verified.first you check if he is registered(if not throw him out right away) and then check if verified you can show error message or stop login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `authenticated` method fires after the user is logged in to the application so your problem is that you are trying to send a logged in user to the login page. If an unverified user tried to visit a protected page, it will let him see it because he is logged in.

A possible solution is to logout if the user is not verified:

```
if($user->verified==false) {
     \Auth::logout();
     flash('you are not verified');
     return redirect('/login');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better method in the AuthenticatesUsers trait to put this code in?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (Auth::user()->verified == 1) 
{
    return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
}
```